# w3wp.exe is restarting but all GET requests are eventually queued and serviced?

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have a w3wp.exe that is restarting on my IIS server (see specs below).  Memory  gradually climbs to ~3G then it randomly restarts itself about every 1-2min.

**Memory Usage:** 
[image]

The odd thing is that once this memory drop (what looks like a restart - btw...the app pool does not get recycled/restarted) happens GET requests are queued but then serviced as soon as the service warms/starts up (causing a delay in responses to our clients - who were initially reporting delayed reponse times on occasion).

I have followed this link to get a stack dump once the .exe restarts (private bytes go to ~0) but nothing gets logged (no .dmp file) with diag debug once the service restarts.

I see tons of warnings in my webserver (IIS) log but that's it:

> A process serving application pool 'MyApplication' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The
>   process id was '1732'. The data field contains the error number.

**ASK:** I'm not sure if this is a memory limitation, if cacheing is not playing well with my threads/tasks, if cacheing is blowing up, if there is  watchdog service restarting my application, etc,.  Has anybody run across something similar with w3wp.exe restarting?  It's hard to tell because diagdebug is not giving me a dump once it restarts.

**SPECS:**

- MVC4 Web API servicing GET requests (code is debug build with debug=true)
- Uses MemoryCache with Model and Business Objects with cache eviction set to 2hrs...uses
- Task (TPS) for each new request.
- Database: SQL Server 2008R2
- Web Servers: Windows Server 2008R2 Enterprise SP1 (64bit, 64G RAM)
- IIS 7.5
- One application pool...no other LOB applications running on this server

Comment: Have you used performance monitor to look at the .NET and/or IIS counters? They might give you a better indication of what's going on. If you've got a MemoryCache setup with 2hrs expiry date then check if that's just using up all of your memory. 

Have you tried to reproduce the scenario with load testing tools in your dev/test environment? Maybe try taking out your caching or turn off debug=true? (definitely make that false BTW) - is your code a release build? What do you mean by Task (TPS) for each new request?

Comment: @LachlanB hi thx 4 repl Which counters? I have been watching quite a few actually, http://bit.ly/138MZr0 but have yet make a correlation. How can I check if memorycache is using up all the memory? I've inherited the code and we don't have a load test environment. Same code is running in our test env but not near the volume. No way can take out cacheing. Have yet to try debug=false. Build is debug build. We create a new task for every http GET that we receive to do work. That task hits the db, cache and makes other external http GETs and then returns a http response. Its super fast ~100ms/req.

Comment: @LachlanB: For Task TPS I meant TPL. We spawn off a thread for each request. (IncomingRequest)->Task.Start(Make http GET to external Service + hit our DB + hit our biz object cache data)...then we have an option in our webconfig to either handle the request WE send asynch or synch.  if synch we use task.wait() within our method then send response. Otherwise, we send what's cached and the task updates the cache and db behind the scenes.

Comment: Why are you using TPL? IIS will take care of that stuff for you. That sounds like overkill to me, I think it's going to be more hassle than it's worth and not really going to give you any extra performance but just complicate things. Have you looked at the aync keyword? eg http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: @LachlanB: Indeed. Like I said it was passed down to me. Agreed that it is a bit over-architected and no need to spawn a new thread for every request that comes in to send an outgoing http requst then get the data and collate for response. I may have to do some re-factoring but would like to find the RC so that I can address the problem first instead of just hacking away. Do you think it has something to do with the threading model in IIS and how I have the workerthreads setup -> http://bit.ly/ZnYw0P?

Comment: I dunno buddy, it could be anything. If it was me I would just rip all of that code out, simplify it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is to reproduce the problem in your test environment. Setup some kind of load generation app (you can write it yourself pretty easily) and get the same problem happening. Then turn off debug in web.config and see if that fixes the issue. Then change it to be a release build and test again.

I've never used memorycache - try reducing the cache eviction time or just turn it off and see  if that fixes the issue. Good luck :)

Comment: That was actually the issue, over use of memorycache where are particular edge case was causing an OOC condition where the application was recursively cacheing itself to death.  No thanks in part to the numerous red herring .dmp's per windbg and debugdiag iis tools.  Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: The perils of over optimisation :) glad I could help.